# Creating symbolic link of different dashboards in different folders in GRAFANA

Tags: grafana

Been searching internet for best practices about this, but could not find any result.

Situation: we would like to have a folder where we do create our dashboards in,
then this would be distributed to other folders for different teams (clients, in our case). The content of these folders is not the same, nor their rights.
What we would like to do is to create something like symbolic link in linux in each of the folders for corresponding dashboards, so when we change one in main folder, it would change in each folder containing that dashboard

If this is not possible, what is the best alternative ?
thx in advance.

Comment: Maybe *Library Panels* would be useful: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/panel-library/

Comment: thx for bringing this feature into light for us. 
Q:It is not at level of dashboards, does this mean we have to move the defined variables manually ? or is there a feature for that as well :-S

Comment: @Matt ps your solution is V8+